# SELECT COUNT with date and type

Tags: php, mysql, count

i have this function :

```
    function get_user_dep($userid)
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total_dep FROM `userdep` WHERE `type` LIKE 'Depozitare' AND DATE(`date`) <= NOW() AND DATE(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $count = $row['total_dep'];
        if ($count > 1) {
            return 'Yes';
        } else {
            return 'No';
            }
    }
with database userdep
id/userid/type/date/amouth
```

i made with assoc, numrow , and it returns me No , and in the database i have more than 4 entrys in interval 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for having to ask this in an answer - my rep is too low. What field type is your date column? From what I just read in your comments on the answer below, the DATE field requires 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Comment: the type of the column is : varchar(255) , and the date is in format date("d m Y") so in my column the date is like this : 14 12 2014

Comment: Pretty sure that's where your problem is. You're trying to compare a VARCHAR/String against a DATE format. Your date field needs to either be a DATE or TIMESTAMP type field to allow for date comparisons.

Comment: thank you scottw33 , i changed the date format date("d m y") in to date("Ymd") , and now i see that it counts me the numbers of deposits , thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

1) SQL is valid.

2) Change this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

to this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

or to this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

3) Also you can try this to check what you received back from DB.

```
echo print_r($row, true);
```

Comment: i get > Array ( [0] => 0 [total_dep] => 0 )

Comment: with assoc i get : Array ( [total_dep] => 0 ) , in my db the date is in format date("d m Y") / 14 12 2014 , if it matters

Comment: Try to run the exact same query against the DB in some front end like phpMyAdmin or by running mysql and connecting to DB. Just to confirm that it is returning count which is more than zero.

Comment: i run it in phpMyAdmin and the return of the query is 0

Comment: run `show create table userdep;` to show the schema.

Comment: I believe you may have an issue with date col which should be either a datetime type of if text then in format YYYY-MM-DD